# How can I remove domain name from a directory/file URI?

Tags: php

I want to be able to remove the domain name (It is dynamic, and changes everytime) to convert this:

```
http://mydomain.com/path/to/file/download.zip
```

To

```
/path/to/file/download.zip
```

**EDIT: The URL is in a string, not $_SERVER REQUEST_URI. It is a string**

How can I do this please? Been trying for hours with parse_url but no luck. The problem is that I do not know the domain, and parse_url only stripped the domain and not the http:// https:// protocol. Please help

Comment: parse_url gives you all the parts of the URL as an array. Take the ones you want.

Comment: If in doubt, show some code

Comment: A little example please?

Comment: probably you are able to go to php.net, and type in "parse_url" yourself?

Comment: I said I tried parse_url, but it stripped the domain, not protocol.

Comment: I am not replacing from $_SERVER request_uri the URL is a string, a custom field value. Not the URL in browser.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with the component PHP_URL_PATH?

```
<?php

$url = 'http://mydomain.com/path/to/file/download.zip';

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

//print /path/to/file/download.zip
```